# InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid - Error getting while sending email using AWS SES service in nestjs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, nestjs, amazon-ses

***welcome.ejs***

```
<p>Hey <%= name %>,</p>
<p>
  Thanks for signing up for Nice App. We're very excited to have you on board.
</p>

<p>To get started using Nice App, please confirm your account below:</p>
<p>
  <a href="<%= confirmation_url %>">Confirm you account</a>
</p>

<p>
  If you're having trouble clicking the confirm account button, copy and paste
  the below URL into your web browser.
</p>

<a href="<%= confirmation_url %>"><%= confirmation_url %></a>
```

I have this email template inside src/core/templates/

***email.service.ts***

```
async sendEmailAWSSES(
    to: string,
    subject: string,
    template: string,
    data: object,
  ) {
    const config = {
      accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      region: 'eu-west-1',
    };

    // Load the HTML template
    const emailTemplateSource = fs.readFileSync(
      `src/core/templates/${template}.ejs`,
      'utf-8',
    );
    const emailTemplate = Handlebars.compile(emailTemplateSource);

    // Compile the HTML template with data
    const html = emailTemplate(data);

    // Create sendEmail params
    const params = {
      Source: 'email@example.com',
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [to],
      },
      Message: {
        Body: {
          Html: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: html,
          },
        },
        Subject: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: subject,
        },
      },
      ReplyToAddresses: [],
    };

    // Create the promise and SES service object
    const sendPromise = await new AWS.SES(config).sendEmail(params).promise();

    return sendPromise;
  }
```

I have this function to send email using AWS SES service
While sending the email i am getting

> InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is
> invalid

Please note that i am using right credentials for AWS SES.

Comment: Are you running this locally? Did you recently update the AWS CLI creds?

Comment: yes, I am running this locally. I have added only accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and region for AWS SES service. Is that anything missing?

Comment: Try deleting `~/.aws/credentials` and run `aws configure`

Comment: Issue resolved by changing credentials

Answer (score 0):

I am using expired credentials that cause an error.